# Directory from WSL in Chrome workspace

Tags: google-chrome, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to add a directory from WSL to Chrome workspace? I used a path I found after executing "explorer.exe ." but it started working very slow and disappeared after a refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tutorial explaining how to mount WSL filesystem as a network drive and adding a folder to Chrome workspace this way works
https://dev.to/themartes_/how-to-make-wsl2-even-faster-with-fast-git-28p8

So you have to type in WSL terminal "explorer.exe .", it will open up an explorer with your home folder from WSL, copy path from explorer (something like \wsl$\Ubuntu) and use it do add a network drive in explorer.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I have added wsl to chrome workspace but it doesn;t actually refresh scss files.